# $P(x-2) - P(2-x) = ax^2-bx+12$ find value of $a+b$?

Tags: polynomials

I'm putting $x=2$ in given equation and getting
$4a-2b+12=0$

But I'm not getting able to proceed further.
Pls help
This came from 2021 - İÜYÖS (and Turkish, Exam for International Students)

Comment: What is $P$? $\quad$

Comment: Not mentioned I'm assuming probability

Comment: Probability of what?

Comment: Hint: $$ax^2-bx+12+a(4-x)^2-b(4-x)+12=0$$ for all $x.$

Comment: How it's zero??

Comment: Don't assume. Why would it be a probability? Just because ir is $P?$  This is not the way capital $P$ is usually used in probabilities. Tell us the context of the question.

Comment: How is what zero??????? Communicating requires an effort on your part. I'm not gonna tell you how t9 solve the problem completely. Think about it for the moment. This is a big hint, almost big enough, I didn't make it. Also, extra question marks looks impatient.

Comment: @SPYadavSir Provide more context.

Comment: $$P(x)-P(-x) = a(x+2)^2-b(x+2)+12$$

Comment: Hi! $P$ probably (!) stands for "polynomial" or some such. But even if it stood for "probability," your question is not fundamentally about probability anyway. I would recommend that you not tag it as `probability` just based on a guess that likely doesn't affect the problem anyway.

Comment: Also: Participation in Math.SE is a two-way street. Your question really ought to provide more context in the way of things like where did this question come from, is it from a course, is it from self-study, what topic are you studying, what you personally think might help (but maybe you don't know how to apply it), and so forth. Put these facts in the original question (not as comments), to avoid down-votes and close-votes.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x-2=y$. Then we get $f(y)-f(-y)=a(y+2)^{2}-b(y+2)+12$ and also

$f(-y)-f(y)=a(-y+2)^{2}-b(-y+2)+12$. Adding the two equations we get:

$0=2ay^{2}+8a-4b+24$ and hence $a=0$ and $b=6$ so $a+b=6$